# Displaying only last ArrayList in android

Tags: android, overriding

I have a two `JSONArray` List contains some values in each case. Now, performing some operation on `Button` what are the last values are those values are displaying but previous array list got override my new array list.

In the below code contains 4 `JSONArray` list named as `numberjson`, `numberjson1`, `cctJsonArray`, `cctJsonArray1`

Each array contains 12 values

**getting this **

> numberjson 24 values[]
>
> cctJsonArray 24 values[]

light_id:01
    intensity:[44,49,0,50,69,56,69,58,53,65,47,66,44,49,0,50,69,56,69,58,53,65,47,66]
    cct:[60,50,59,61,39,47,46,49,53,41,0,0,60,50,59,61,39,47,46,49,53,41,0,0]

```
 public void getCCTAndIntensityValues (String schedulerType) {

            if (simpleSwitch1.isOn()) {
                int cct1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
                int cct2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
                int cct3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
                int cct4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
                int cct5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
                int cct6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
                int cct7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
                int cct8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
                int cct9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
                int cct10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
                int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
                int cct12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


                int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
                int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
                int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
                int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
                int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
                int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
                int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
                int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
                int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
                int intensity10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
                int intensity11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
                int intensity12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

                try {
                    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                    number.add(intensity1);
                    number.add(intensity2);
                    number.add(intensity3);
                    number.add(intensity4);
                    number.add(intensity5);
                    number.add(intensity6);
                    number.add(intensity7);
                    number.add(intensity8);
                    number.add(intensity9);
                    number.add(intensity10);
                    number.add(intensity11);
                    number.add(intensity12);

                    numberJson = new JSONArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                        numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

                    }


                    ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                    cctvalues.add(cct1);
                    cctvalues.add(cct2);
                    cctvalues.add(cct3);
                    cctvalues.add(cct4);
                    cctvalues.add(cct5);
                    cctvalues.add(cct6);
                    cctvalues.add(cct7);
                    cctvalues.add(cct8);
                    cctvalues.add(cct9);
                    cctvalues.add(cct10);
                    cctvalues.add(cct11);
                    cctvalues.add(cct12);


                    cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    if (cctJsonArray != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {
                            cctJsonArray.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));

                        }

                    }


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                int cct111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
                int cct21 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
                int cct31 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
                int cct41 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
                int cct51 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
                int cct61 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
                int cct71 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
                int cct81 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
                int cct91 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
                int cct101 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
                int cct1111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
                int cct121 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


                int intensity111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
                int intensity21 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
                int intensity31 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
                int intensity41 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
                int intensity51 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
                int intensity61 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
                int intensity71 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
                int intensity81 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
                int intensity91 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
                int intensity101 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
                int intensity1111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
                int intensity121 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

                try {

                    ArrayList<Integer> number1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    number1.add(intensity111);
                    number1.add(intensity21);
                    number1.add(intensity31);
                    number1.add(intensity41);
                    number1.add(intensity51);
                    number1.add(intensity61);
                    number1.add(intensity71);
                    number1.add(intensity81);
                    number1.add(intensity91);
                    number1.add(intensity101);
                    number1.add(intensity1111);
                    number1.add(intensity121);

                    numberJson1 = new JSONArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < number1.size(); i++) {

                        numberJson1.put(i, number1.get(i));

                    }


                    ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    cctvalues1.add(cct111);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct21);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct31);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct41);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct51);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct61);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct71);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct81);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct91);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct101);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct1111);
                    cctvalues1.add(cct121);


                    cctJsonArray1 = new JSONArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues1.size(); i++) {

                        cctJsonArray1.put(i, cctvalues1.get(i));

                    }



                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberJson1.length(); i++) {
                        numberJson.put(numberJson1.get(i));
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < cctJsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                        //JSONObject jsonObject = cctJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        cctJsonArray.put(cctJsonArray1.get(i));
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Comment: it can only have 12 item you are setting an if and only put 12 item at both condition

Comment: both conditions should execute  and my requirement is 24 values not 12 values

Comment: You will get 12 for both conditions

Comment: remove the if condition

Comment: i want from frst json array 12 values and second json array 12 values then total 24 values want

Comment: you have to move the if condition so you will have a 4 arrays with 12 value and 2 with 24 item

Comment: where want to move

Comment: can you please edit my code and let me know where i did the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try like this following according to your requirement:**

```
try
            {

                ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                number.add(1);
                number.add(2);
                number.add(3);
                number.add(4);
                number.add(5);
                number.add(6);
                number.add(7);
                number.add(8);
                number.add(9);
                number.add(10);
                number.add(11);
                number.add(12);

                JSONArray numberJson = new JSONArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                    numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

                }


                ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                cctvalues.add(13);
                cctvalues.add(14);
                cctvalues.add(15);
                cctvalues.add(16);
                cctvalues.add(17);
                cctvalues.add(18);
                cctvalues.add(19);
                cctvalues.add(20);
                cctvalues.add(21);
                cctvalues.add(22);
                cctvalues.add(23);
                cctvalues.add(24);


                JSONArray cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                if (cctJsonArray != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {
                        numberJson.put(cctvalues.get(i));

                    }
                }



            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Hope it will help you**

Comment: @jyo cha, If above solution helped you and solved your problem then mark this answer as correct and upvote it so that it will help to other users.

Comment: what about cctjsonarray

Comment: am getting 24 values but repated the 12 values

Comment: `mCCT1.getProgress()` and `Intenisty.getProgress()` to till 12 both. Why are you doing again this operation as you done and below that, you are doing same again?

Comment: for day and night

Comment: @jyocha, `numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));` contains `intensity` that you put into `numberJson` and again you are doing the same thing here  `numberJson.put(numberJson1.get(i));`. That's why it has added 12 `intensity` values and again you added same. Both `intensity` that you are getting are same value 12 up and 12 down.

Comment: apending both numberjson and nuberjson1

Comment: Yes, here is the problem. You are getting `intensity` 12 and 12 again. Both `intensity` is having the same value.

Comment: `int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));`
 `int intensity111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));`

Comment: For day 12 values and for night 12 values those are not same

Comment: They are the same buddy. See this First `int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));` and then see this where you are getting same intensity again and it has same value here `int intensity111 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));`.

Comment: Search in your code `mIntenisty1.getProgress()` and you will know how many times you are using the same. As I have seen your code you are using twice.

Comment: can you move this discussion to chat

Comment: yes want twice for day mintensity1.getprogress for night also same mintensity1.getprogress. am just changing the toggle switch to day and night